# Higgs Field before or after Cosmological Inflation?

Tags: cosmology, higgs, symmetry-breaking, cosmological-inflation

Question:
When exactly did the Higgs Field begin to exist (before cosmological inflation or after cosmological inflation)?

Comment: All fields have presumably existed forever--they are part of the woodwork; how do you reckon otherwise?

Comment: Are you asking when the electroweak symmetry breaking transition occurred (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/392526)?

Comment: after all, these   are models. There are models where it is the Higgs field that generates inflation https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0708

Comment: Dear anna v, dear Chiral Anomaly, dear Cosmas Zachos, dear Qmechanic. Thank you very much for your prompt responses. They are all VERY HELPFUL. I still need some time to digest. Are there any further comments? To be continued…

Comment: a) 5.39 × 10 −44 sec: Planck-Time; b) 10 −43 sec: Grand Unified Theory (GUT)- Era; c.) 10 −35 sec:  Beginning of Cosmological Inflation; d) between 10 −33 sec and 10 −30 sec: Ending of Cosmological Inflation; e) approx. 10 −10 sec: Higgs-Field/ breaking of symmetry triggers the Higgs mechanism