# What would happen to the physical photon if the electroweak symmetry were to be restored?

Tags: standard-model, electroweak

Suppose the Higgs field goes back to its initial unstable state, as it was before electroweak symmetry breaking. Or, in other words, suppose the electroweak symmetry is restored. Since, the physical photon that we observe today was, before symmetry breaking, a linear combination of $W^{0}$ and $B^{0}$, would it "decompose" back to being that linear combination if the symmetry is to be restored?

Comment: Related: [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241609/restoration-of-spontaneously-broken-symmetry-at-high-energy), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119921/are-there-massless-bosons-at-scales-above-electroweak-scale/119929#119929), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/392471/electroweak-symmetry-breaking-and-the-early-universe) and links therefrom.

Comment: This  $v\to 0$ is a delicate limit, assuming you keep the couplings and so the Weinberg angle fixed. For anything but absolute *v* = 0, you have the photon a massless mixed state, and three massive vectors; at the absolute point, you have a massless hypercharge *B* and confined SU(2) singlets. You are interested in the transition/crossover, or just in the absolute destination?